# Printing letters from a File 3 Letters at a Time in Python

Tags: python, file

I am trying to write a function that opens a filename, reads the contents of the file, and then prints the contents 3 letters at a time.
Here is what I have tried:

```
def trigram_printer(filename):

    open_file = open(filename)
    copy = open_file
    three_letters = copy.read(4)


    for contents in copy:
        print(three_letters)

    open_file.close
```

Comment: I know I need to make the function repeat, but I am having trouble with this.

Comment: how big is the file?

Comment: What is the point of the copy? You know that they reference the same object.

Comment: initiate a counter, read character by character in a loop, increment the counter for each character, and when it hits three: print a new line and set the counter to  zero again...

Comment: Its just a small text file

Answer (score 3):

There are several things I’d change about this code:

- You never update the `three_letters` variable, which is why it prints the same thing repeatedly. You need to update the value of `three_letters` (by reading three more characters from the file) after you print it.
- You copy the `open_file` object, when I’d just use it directly.
- By doing `.read(4)`, you print the contents 4 letters at a time, not 3.
- You’re using the `f = open(filename); ...; f.close()` construction, rather than the more conventional `with open(filename) as f; ...`.

With those thoughts in mind, here’s how I’d write your trigram printer:

```
def trigram_printer(filename):
    """Prints the contents of <filename>, three characters at a time."""
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        three_letters = f.read(3)

        while three_letters:
            print(three_letters)
            three_letters = f.read(3)
```

The key part is that every time `three_letters` gets printed, this function reads the next three characters from the file. When it runs out of characters, `three_letters` will be an empty string and the while loop will stop.

Answer (score 0):

`copy` simply points to `open_file` and your printing the letters for the number of lines in `copy`:

```
with open('test.txt') as open_file:
    data = open_file.read(3)

    while data != '':
        print(data) # print 3-gram
        data = open_file.read(3)
```

Just use a continuous loop to test if the file buffer is empty and print the data during the iteration.